# Duda en Multiplicación SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, sql

**tengo una duda con una multiplicación que hace un Stored Procedure la cual hace lo que se muestra a continuación:**

```
declare 
 @a decimal(38,20),
 @b decimal(38,6),
 @c decimal(38,6)

set @a =0.00042500000000000000 
set @b =    0.000762
set @c  =1800.000000
select @a*@b*@c

**
El problema es que el resultado de la multiplicación me da 0 y no entiendo el porque.
Espero me puedan apoyar
**
```

Comment: Lo que ocurre en tu caso, [está explicado aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) con todo detalle. Tu consulta arrojaría un resultado adecuado con algo así más o menos: `select CAST(@a AS DECIMAL(30,20))*CAST(@b AS DECIMAL(30,20))*CAST(@c AS DECIMAL(30,20));`

Comment: Para no perder precisión yo lo pasaría a `float`.  `select cast(cast(@a as float) * cast(@b as float) * cast(@c as float) as decimal(38,20))`

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano ahora ya entiendo por que no me daba el resultado.